# For any point in $\Bbb R^2$ $f$ has a local inverse. Can I say $f$ is invertible on its range?

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

> Define $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ by $$\begin{align}f(x,y)=(e^{2x+y},4x^2+4xy+y^2+6x+4y)\ . \end{align}$$
> Define $U:=f(\Bbb R^2)$.
> Prove that the inverse function of $f$ (say $f^{-1}:U\to \Bbb R^2$) exists.

I want to apply the inverse function theorem. I know that $f$ is $C^1$ and the Jacorbian determinant $J_f(x,y)=2e^{2x+y}>0$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$. But I have a question. If I know that for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$, I can find a local inverse, does this imply $f$ has a inverse from its range $U$ onto $\Bbb R^2$? Or I need to find some ways to prove that $f$ is injective from $\Bbb R^2$ to $U$?

Comment: Local inverse exists at every point the domain does not imply the global inverse exists.

Comment: What should I do to prove that  the inverse function of $f$ exists?

Comment: Have you tried to solve $e^{2x+y} = u$,$4x^2+4xy+y^2+6x+4y = v$?

Comment: Perhaps having a look to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.24033/bsmf.771) by Jacques Hadamard will answer your question: local invertibility will not solve your question, but local invertibility+something else (compactness of the map) will give you global invertibility (even in the infinite dimensional case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local invertibility without injectivity cannot give you global invertibility.
But here injectivity is easy to prove, as well as an explicit formula for the inverse. If
$$(e^{2x+y}, 4x^2+4xy+y^2+6x+4y) = (a, b)$$
then
$$y = \ln(a) - 2x$$
and you can check that
$$b = 4x^2+4xy+y^2+6x+4y = - 2x + 4 \ln(a) + \ln(a)^2.$$
You can easily conclude with this.